# Custom UserChecker in HWIOauthBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony4, hwioauthbundle

I have a problem with FOSUserBundle and HWIOauthBundle. I use custom `UserChecker` to check whether user is banned (custom table in database as I need a ban history). When I use Facebook to log-in my `CustomChecker` is not used. It does work when I'm using login and password as authentication.

Issue on GitHub: https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/issues/1358

Anyone has an idea how to fix that?

Comment: can't you override hwi_oauth.user_checker?

Answer (score 1):

from the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/override.html)

> Services & Configuration
>
> If you want to modify service definitions of another bundle, you can
>   use a compiler pass to change the class of the service or to modify
>   method calls. In the following example, the implementing class for the
>   `original-service-id` is changed to `App\YourService`:

```
// src/Kernel.php
namespace App;

// ...
+ use App\Service\YourService;
+ use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
+ use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;

class Kernel extends BaseKernel implements CompilerPassInterface
{
+     public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
+     {
+         $definition = $container->findDefinition('original-service-id');
+         $definition->setClass(YourService::class);
+     }
}
```

Comment: There is no need to do this in your Kernel. You can override the service within `services.yml` or any other format you use. 
@simivar 
If you think overriding HWIO user checker / security checker might help, you can override it by defining your *Checker class as a service. I would guess this is the id of the checker `security.authorization_checker`

Comment: @domagoj03 I am not sure that you can override bundle service in `services.yml`

Comment: I am sure you can :) Despite the fact that half of my code is run this way, I tried it again to make sure and yeah, you can override (any, probably) service with your own simply by giving it the same Id - the lowercase, snakecase definition, within `services.yml`, within any registered bundle.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm, the solution of @Domagoj work for Symfony 3.4.

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
...
    security.user_checker:
        class: AppBundle\Service\YourUserChecker
```

With this code, the hwi.user_checker is override by your UserChecker.

Thanks.